# Template mixed env types via Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I would like to have a single environment section in my values file where I can define both the usual environment type and the secretRef environment type. Is it possible to achieve this in Helm templating?

Example what I'm trying to achieve

```yaml
env:
  ADDRESS: http://some.url
  FETCH-INTERVAL: 1m
  USERNAME:
    secretName: some_secret
    key: username
  PASSWORD:
    secretName: some_secret
    key: password
```

Here is what i have at this moment in my deployment.yaml

```yaml
          env:
            {{- if .Values.env }}
              {{- range $k, $v := .Values.env }}
            - name: {{ $k | quote }}
                {{- if eq $v.type "secretRef" }}
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ $v.name | quote }}
                  key: {{ $v.key | quote }}
                {{- else if eq $v.type "configMapRef" }}
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: {{ $v.name | quote }}
                  key: {{ $v.key | quote }}
                {{- else }}
              value: {{ $v.value | quote }}
                {{- end }}
              {{- end }}
            {{- end }}
```

I have some draft which works, but in this case, i always need to set the env type

```yaml
env:
  ADDRESS:
    type: string
    value: http://some.url
  FETCH-INTERVAL:
    type: string
    value: 1m
  USERNAME:
    type: secretRef
    name: some_secret
    key: username
  PASSWORD:
    type: secretRef
    name: some_secret
    key: password
```

Comment: That file on its own would be valid to put in a Helm `templates/deployment.yaml` file, and you could definitely construct it.  What input are you hoping to provide in the `values.yaml` to produce it?  What have you tried so far to achieve this?